# Partially specialize class template by lambda

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++14, variadic-templates

I have template type that store information about function or member function (like return type, number or parameters and so on).

```cpp
template<class R, class... FuncParams>
struct SFuncInfo
{
    using Signature = R(FuncParams...);
    using Ret = R;

    static constexpr size_t numParams = sizeof...(FuncParams);
};

// member
template<class T, class Ret, class... Params>
struct SFuncInfo<Ret(T::*)(Params...)> : SFuncInfo<Ret, Params...> 
{
    static constexpr bool isMemberFunction = true;
};

// function
template<class R, class... FuncParams>
struct SFuncInfo<R(FuncParams...)> : SFuncInfo<R, FuncParams...> 
{
    static constexpr bool isMemberFunction = false;
};
```

This is how it can be used:

```cpp
int func(const char* str) { return 1; }

struct MyType
{
    bool memFunc(int val, float fl) { return true; }
};

int main() 
{
    static_assert(!SFuncInfo<decltype(func)>::isMemberFunction, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same<SFuncInfo<decltype(func)>::Ret, int>::value, "");

    static_assert(SFuncInfo<decltype(&MyType::memFunc)>::isMemberFunction, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same<SFuncInfo<decltype(&MyType::memFunc)>::Ret, bool>::value, "");
}
```

This code compiles. But I want also to handle cases with lambdas. Something like this:

```cpp
auto lambda = [](int, bool) -> float { return 3.14f; };

static_assert(SFuncInfo<decltype(lambda)>::isMemberFunction, "");
static_assert(std::is_same<SFuncInfo<decltype(lambda)>::Ret, float>::value, "");
```

I tried different option. Few of the are listed below.

```cpp
template<class T>
struct SFuncInfo<T, decltype(T())>
{
    static constexpr bool isMemberFunction = true;
};

template<class T>
struct SFuncInfo<T, decltype(&std::decay<decltype(std::declval<T>())>::type::operator())>
{
    static constexpr bool isMemberFunction = true;
};
```

It doesn't resolve to any of these specialization.

By the way, the code below also compiles:

```cpp
auto lambda = [](int, bool) -> float { return 3.14f; };

using LambdaType = std::decay<decltype(std::declval<decltype(lambda)>())>::type;
using CallOperator = decltype(&LambdaType::operator());
static_assert(std::is_same<SFuncInfo<CallOperator>::Ret, float>::value, "");
static_assert(SFuncInfo<CallOperator>::isMemberFunction, "");
```

Here is [LIVE DEMO](https://godbolt.org/z/if1R84) is someone wants to play around.

Does anyone has a good solution for this?

Comment: Isn't `std::decay<decltype(std::declval<T>())>::type` just `std::decay_t<T>`?

Comment: Your current code breaks for a 0 argument free function that returns a 0 argument member function pointer (and it only narrowly avoids that problem for free functions because you can only return function pointers [which you don't specialize on for free functions], not functions). This is because you repurpose `R` in your specializations as input template parameter, so if the `SFuncInfo<Ret, Params...>` you inherit from has empty `Params` and `Ret` can be specialized on again, you lose. Please don't repurpose the template parameters like that. https://godbolt.org/z/wuGAEc

Comment: @MaxLanghof, thanks for the comment. Very useful, but could you elaborate more about repurposing? Maybe an example?

Comment: @Peregrin The first template argument is called `R` as in `ReturnType`. But the semantics of your specializations are "`R` is the function (pointer) type to inspect". It happens to work in 99% of the cases, but the fact that `SFuncInfo<int*>` semantically resolves to "the type _returned_ for a function that returns `int*` and takes no params" while `SFuncInfo<int(*)()>` resolves to "the type used to _deduce_ the information for a function that returns `int*` and takes no params" is problematic because `R` is not the return value but the input type in the latter case. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: @MaxLanghof, I think I understand. But it seems like this problem is fixed by solution proposed by GuillaumeRacicot below. Wouldn't you agree?

Comment: @Peregrin Yes, that solution separates into `SFuncInfoBase` which stores the information and `SFuncInfo` which is responsible for deducing what to store in its `SFuncInfoBase`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution would be to make an overload that is only available to callable object types and inherit from `SFuncInfo` with the `operator()` type.

```
template<typename T>
struct SFuncInfo<T, decltype(void(&T::operator()))> : SFuncInfo<decltype(&T::operator())> {};
//     constraint ----------------^
```

However to support this I separated the specializations and the metadata classes, splitting them into `SFuncInfo` and `SFuncInfoBase`:

```
template<class R, class... FuncParams>
struct SFuncInfoBase
{
    using Signature = R(FuncParams...);
    using Ret = R;

    static constexpr size_t numParams = sizeof...(FuncParams);
};

template<class T, typename = void>
struct SFuncInfo;

// member
template<class T, class Ret, class... Params>
struct SFuncInfo<Ret(T::*)(Params...)const> : SFuncInfo<Ret(T::*)(Params...)> {};

template<class T, class Ret, class... Params>
struct SFuncInfo<Ret(T::*)(Params...)> : SFuncInfoBase<Ret, Params...> 
{
    static constexpr bool isMemberFunction = true;
};
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/00SlT0)

Comment: I fully agree that the metadata should be separate from the specializations. Otherwise it's far from trivial to prove that this cannot go recursive or misbehave in some other way (if functions return other function pointers for example).

Answer (score 3):

Adding this single partial specialization works on my side:

```
template<class Lambda>
struct SFuncInfo<Lambda> : SFuncInfo<decltype(&Lambda::operator())> { };
```

Comment: this is very elegant solution but it turns out that it doesn't work for member functions without parameters. I update the link to live demo to add this case.